# String pointer in C overwriting existing pointer

Tags: c, pointers

I have been having a very strange problem in a C program with variables overwriting each other. I have a variable `logFilePath` which is defined like this:

```
logFilePath = pathToFile(logDirectory,argv[2]);
```

The function pathToFile is implemented like this.

```
char *pathToFile(char *directory, char *file) {
  char *filePath = malloc(sizeof(*directory)+sizeof(*file)+10);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; directory[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if (directory[i+1] == '\0' && directory[i] != '/') strcat(directory,"/");
  }
  strcat(filePath, directory);
  strcat(filePath, file);
  return filePath;
}
```

For some reason logFilePath is getting modified by a completely unrelated function. The function in which it gets modified is called like this

```
line = getIdentifierFromLine(line);
```

And the implementation.

```
char *getIdentifierFromLine(char *line) {
  char *ident = malloc(sizeof(char)*30);
  int i = 0;
    printf("%s\n", ident);
  while (line[i] != ';') {
    ident[i] = line[i];
    i++;
  }
  return ident;
}
```

The problem is that the logFilePaths piece seems to be the same ident, namely the half after the first 15 characters. ident is initialised to the part after the first 15 chars of logFileDirectory and changing the value of each char in ident changes it in logFileDirectory.What is going on here?

Comment: `sizeof(*directory)` and `sizeof(*file)` meant `sizeof(char)`

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by changing the malloc for filePath in pathToFile to `sizeof(char)*150`. I still don't understand why I didn't get a segmentation fault?

Comment: filePath isn't "". change `strcat(filePath, directory);` to `strcpy(filePath, directory);`

Comment: Yeah your problem is going to be related to the fact that you're only `malloc`ing exactly 12 bytes.  You don't necessarily get a seg fault, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @sqykly so is it just a nuance of the compiler that ident overlaps with the end of logFilePath?

Comment: also Space to add the string does it exist in the `directory` ?

Comment: This depends on memory blocks available on the heap that can be overwritten, and in such a case there will be no segmentation fault, only a corrupted heap.
As BLUEPIXY has pointed out `sizeof(*directory) == sizeof(char)` (usually == 1 byte). So you are actually allocating 12 bytes instead of sizeof(char) * (directory_length + file_length) + 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` does not do string length checking. This:

```
char *filePath = malloc(sizeof(*directory)+sizeof(*file)+10);
```

is wrong. `sizeof(*directory)` gives the size of a char (which is usually 1).

What you want is this:

```
char *filePath = malloc(strlen(directory)+strlen(directory)+2);
```

2 extra is enough, one for the optional `/` and one for the null terminating character.

Because of this, you do not allocate enough memory for your file path, resulting in undefined behaviour. In your case, the overwriting of buffers. It could also lead to segfaults or other weird things (I had this once where a valid piece of code segfaulted, because I made a mistake somewhere else.)

Comment: sizeof(*directory) gives the size of a char not a pointer to char, so  probably 1

Comment: Yes, sizeof(variable) is more confusing than sizeof(type) imo.

Answer (score 0):

The standard method of logging (in my experience) is to use either the stdout or stderr streams. In C++ to use these you would need to include iostream, and use as below:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using std::cout;
  using std::cerr;
  using std::endl;

  cout << "Output message" << endl;
  cerr << "Error message" << endl;
}
```

This, however, only achieves printing to those outputs, which usually end up at a terminal. If you want to use these standard stream methods (which are quite readable) to output to a file, then you have to redirect your output somehow. One way of doing this is by using the freopen function, provided by cstdio. What this does is open a file, and moves a given stream to that file. See here for documentation. An example would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  using namespace std;
  freopen( "output.txt", "w", stdout );
  freopen( "error.txt", "w", stderr );

  cout << "Output message" << endl;
  cerr << "Error message" << endl;
}
```

Comment: logFilePath is not the applications log, it is simply a variable name. Also the application is in C not C++.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the size calculation when you allocate space for `filePath`:

```
char *filePath = malloc(sizeof(*directory)+sizeof(*file)+10);
```

Here `directory` is of type `char*`, so `*directory` has type `char` and `sizeof(*directory)` is `1`. The same happens for `sizeof(*file)` and only 12 bytes of memory get allocated.

If this is not enough space, the path is written past the end of the buffer, into space that later ends up belonging to `ident` in that other function. Then writing to `*indent` modifies the same memory that is occupied by the end of `filePath`.

Instead of `sizeof` you should use `strlen()` to determine the length of the input strings:

```
char *filePath = malloc(strlen(directory)+strlen(file)+10);
```